# How can I close native date picker programmatically ionic 2?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

Using ionic 2 native plugin date picker to acquire date but l faced problem when receive notification and picker opened. When click on notification and push view date picker still opened in new view,
How to force native datepicker to close or fire cancel button in native date picker before leave view? 
Or what is the best way to navigate inside app while receiving notification to close any open native components such as date picker?